# What "timeline" technology is being referenced in the Google/Arcade Fire Video Experiment?

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

In the really cool video at http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/, what exactly is being done here to keep all the videos/activity perfectly synchronized to the audio?

I'm having trouble finding good details on exactly what kinds of syncing are actually possible via HTML5.  I would like to synchronize some videos, audio tracks, and HTML overlays together, and I'm wondering what the best approach is for getting a solid timeline that will drop frames, client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing its in HTML5 and Javascript. In HTML5, you can use what are called "cuepoints" to trigger certain events. Basically, you say something like "at this timestamp in the video, trigger this event". At my place of employment, these cuepoints can be embedded as metadata in the media file, and read as they are decoded. This is a heavy approach, but could be doable if you had the time and the tools.

However, for most web applications, I would suggest using Javascript, specifically the libraries [here](http://cuepoint.org/)(cuepoint.js; more for subtitles) or [here](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js)(popcorn.js). Either might come in handy for your application.

In Regular HTML5, there *is* a spec for specifying cuepoint data, but that is still in flux and YMMV in different browsers and environments.

Comment: Excellent advice... Cuepoint.js is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.  At your company, for "at this timestamp in the video, trigger this event", are you using cuepoint.js, or some other method?

Comment: We run all our stuff in Silverlight, but I have dabbled in stuff like this as well. Usually, we use metadata inside media files to trigger our cuepoints.